# Best practice of designing JPARepository(ies) for ORM Domain graph

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have been designing spring rest apis using standard MVC architecture like domain layer as POJOs and repositories to fetch domain data from db tables. So far these entities were isolated so the design acted as separate RestController, Service, and Repository flow for each entity. 
I have been looking to understand the best practice when it comes to association in domain objects i.e., ORM.  For example, lets take following pseudocode to illustrate domain classes (only for the purpose to express the design in question. I have not provided complete classes):

```
public class Customer {
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Order> orders;

    //...getters setters
}

public class Order {
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column;
    private String orderNumber;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Product> products;

    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    //...getters setters
}

 public class Product {
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column;
    private String productName;

    @ManyToOne
    private Order order;

    //...getters setters
}
```

The dilemma I have from designing perspective. I have following approaches that very well all be incorrect:

1. Define one RestController for customer and provide all the api resources like /customers,  /customers/id/orders, /customers/id/orders/id/products etc.  Have one Service that takes care of working with these domains. Have separate JPARepository for EACH domain. The "keep it simple" thing here is that I have separete repository for each domain so I just have to provide query methods in corresponding Repository class in order to find details for a specific domain i.e., fetch orders for a given customer Id.  However, that makes me think killing the purpose of using ORM model because I am fetching individual domains through their Repository classes. This option will make all 3 repository classes wired in the service class and that also I think is not a good design. 3 might looks okay here but I have 6 to 7 domains in the ORM graph in my actual requirements so that would mean autowiring 6 repositoris in one service class.
2. One RestController and one Service class as in above option but the Repository class is single too. The Repository is created only for Customer domain. In this way I retrieve Customers with other domaims lazy loaded. This is to fulfil a GET request of  "/customers".  To fulfil a GET request of "/customers/id/orders" I will again use Customer Repository, retrieve customer for the given Id and then return list of Orders. Further, for a GET request of  "/customers/id/orders/id/products" , I will require writing a manual data fetching mechanism in Customer domain so that it takes care of retrieving list of products for a given customerId and orderId.  This way I use one Repository, satisfying the purpose of using ORM but then adding manual fetching data methods in Customer domain. Another negative I see is that I need to get complete list of orders in a customer domain even if I have customerId and orderId available. I would have fetched one single order based on customerId and orderId has I used a separate repository for Order.
3. Both are incorrect and there exists a better approach.

I have looked through [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) for repository and hibernate docs for ORM. I went through multiple tutorials for one-to-many mappings with spring data rest but I found mixed approaches in different tutorials.

This question will look duplicate to you as I have read multiple posts on stackoverflow regarding this design concern but none of the answers give me a reasoning for the trade offs and options I mentioned above. Hence, I am reposting this question.

Answer (score 0):

It is a mixed approach. e.g. in your case the product entity need not have a @ManyToOne relation with the Order. Imagine if your product is part of 1 million orders! How many time will you query a product to find orders? You will query findOrdersByProduct(Product) rather than findProductByOrder(Order)

1. think w.r.t your usecase. Sometimes it makes sense to have one directional mapping if you will never fetch the information other than from the owner of the relationship
2. Think about the amount of data that you will fetch (including the joins) if you query an entity.
3. e.g if i am fetching an organization do i need to fetch all its employees? your system will go for a toss (lazy loading will save you most of the time but if you have an Angular then it will bind and fetch the entire model). But it does make sense to have many to one relationship with an org from the employee entity.